# Datagrid: How to get the CurrentCell of the SelectedItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Within a WPF datagrid's code behind, how do I get the currentCell from my dataGrid.SelectedItem (In Code)?

Many Thanks,

Comment: What is ItemsSource of DataGrid?

Comment: haris, the item source is RowViewModel. In case you are wondering, what I am doing in the view's code behind. I am trying to fix some ui issues with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this from [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/74332b78-6bfd-4ac9-af85-dfd9bec87a29)

You can retrieve row from `dataGrid.SelectedIndex` and column by `dataGrid.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex`

```
public static DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid dataGrid, int row, int column)
        {
            DataGridRow rowContainer = GetRow(dataGrid, row);
            if (rowContainer != null)
            {
                DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);

                // try to get the cell but it may possibly be virtualized
                DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
                if (cell == null)
                {
                    // now try to bring into view and retreive the cell
                    dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, dataGrid.Columns[column]);

                    cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
                }

                return cell;
            }

            return null;
}
```

Edit

```
public static DataGridRow GetRow(DataGrid dataGrid, int index)
    {
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        if (row == null)
        {

            dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid.Items[index]);
            dataGrid.UpdateLayout();

            row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        }

        return row;
    }
```

you can find the complete source code [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/11/05/wpf-datagrid-new-item-template-sample.aspx) (look for code at end of page)

Comment: haris, this sounds very promising. A pity they didnt implement the GetRow. DataGridRow rowContainer = GetRow(dataGrid, row);  I thought first I could use datagrid.SelectedItem, but this would give me the ViewModel instead not the row...what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks Harris. i also found this page. Its using Extension methods, very similar to yours. I am almost there.  The last problem is I needed to extract a DataGridCellInfo. From my understanidng DataGridCellInfo is a column with additional row information. Do you have any idea how to retrieve that? I am trying to set dataGrid.CurrentCell in programmatic way

Comment: Do you want `DataGridCell` or `DataGridCellInfo`?

Comment: both :) I got now DataGridCell, and I am happy. But I just realized I also needed DataGridCellInfo.  Is there a way to retrieve that too?

Comment: No worries harris. i found an alternative way. I needed to set the datagrid.CurrentCell programatically, this call be simply done by getting teh cell as you suggested and setting the Cell.focus() Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use CurrentCell.Item Property in the DataGrid itself:

```
DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)myDataGrid.CurrentCell.Item;
```

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'RowViewModel' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell'.

Comment: Remove the `.Item`. It points to what is inside your DataGridCell, not the actual DataGridCell

Comment: Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellInfo' to 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell'